# Super key combinations for media keys don't work

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

My keyboard doesn't have media keys and I've always used <kbd>Super</kbd> shortcuts for media keys. However in Ubuntu 12.04 they no longer work.

I want:

- <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> - Play/Pause
- <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> - Stop
- <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> - Previous
- <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> - Next

I've tried replacing "Super" with "Mod4" in `gconf-editor` in /apps/gnome_settings_daemon/keybindings after setting them in `Settings` → `Keyboard` → `Shortcuts`.

I've checked other keybinding locations but have found no other media keybinding settings in `gconf-editor`.

My muscle memory thanks you in advance ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/951805